# How to convert text file in bytes to readable data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having problems reading data into a 'normal' dataframe from an .dat.gz archive, which I saved in my set working directory. My code is:

```
import gzip

filename = (r"C:\Users\Van\Desktop\Python\Book st 2 - AlD\AlD-Bookst2-master\code\2005Tats.dat.gz")

with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as a_file:
    bytes_data = a_file.read()
```

and then I've tried converting the bytes to 'normal' strings and/or integer like so:

```
from io import StringIO

s = str(bytes_data, 'utf-8')
data = StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_csv(data)

print(df.head())
```

But the problem is that I got the following output... and it appears that it is still in bytes! So, I'm finding it very hard to make sense of the data

[image: output]

I tried to have a quick look with df.info() and it returns this:

[image: output from pd.info]

I've also tried pd.read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,
            compression='gzip', 
            header=None, 
            delim_whitespace=True,
            error_bad_lines=False)
```

But I get...
[image: output alternative]

Here is a screenshot of the .dat file contained inside the archive (notepad was the only application that could open the .dat file in my pc):

[image: screenshot of dat file]

**UPDATE 1:** I tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(filename, colspecs = 'infer', infer_rows = 10)

print(df)
```

and I get this output...
[image: output from update1]

My Python version is v3.7.9 and Pandas is 1.2.3. Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: How is the `.dat` file structured? Are you sure the data in it is binary and needs to be read as a bytes object?

Comment: @MattDMo Yes... or so it appears.  I opened the .dat file with note pad and it is no different from what I've been getting, though it is huge. I've even tried using 'r' instead of 'rb' and no difference.

Comment: `pd.read_csv` can handle compression so you can read it at once with `pd.read_csv(filename)`. I would be more worried about the content of the file once decompressed, as Python was complaining about inconsistent number of columns per line. Can you post some example data from the `.dat` file?

Comment: This looks like a [fixed-width format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) file to me. Parsing these correctly is usually dependent on the exact format of the file. Can you decompress the file and provide, say, the first ten lines?

Comment: @CodeDifferent  Yes, I did try but got the same output as above. I've edited my question to include a screenshot example data of the .dat file, it wouldn't let me attach it to the comments.

Comment: Where does the file come from, what generated it?  What do you expect the content to be?

Comment: @NickODell  Yes, so I tried:

` df = pd.read_fwf(filename, colspecs = 'infer', infer_rows = 10)

print(df)` 

Though I noticed that it did cleared the console as it run... which I thought it was odd. I've edited my question above to for the output because I get a warning saying it is too long for the comments section :(

Comment: @PierreD Yes, so the file contains data on female pregnancies for a specific year and I'd expect there to be a mix of Boolean flags, discrete values for categories as well as floats/integers. The data supposedly comes from the NSFG

Comment: If at all possible, you'll save yourself time by asking or searching for a proper description of the file format. Even if you reverse-engineer what it is, there could be special fields with meanings that are hard to infer. One email to the right person, plus a bit of patience, will pay off.

Comment: @PierreD Yes... well I understood that the .dat file can be any format (correct me if wrong) and there is a codebook available for this particular dataset however, this only tells me what the columns contain, whether it is computed or not and it gives you small example of a few rows. The only thing  can infer is that there are 173 columns and 10215 rows. But nothing with regards to data types or file types we'd use in python.

Comment: No, I mean a proper format specification. It should cover everything, how to retrieve the various fields, and how to interpret them (what some of the numeric codes mean, if there are any).